# Ubuntu Startup EDAC Error

Tags: 20.04

I have had this for a few days now. Ubuntu will give me the error EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 0. Then Ubuntu will startup like normal. I have tried:
Everything other AskUbuntu pages have suggested to fix this.
Updating Ubuntu
Downgrading Ubuntu
And using Timeshift to restore previous snapshots of my OS

The error, after this it goes to the normal Ubuntu loading screen:

[image: Screen photo]

I am currently on 20.04, but I did try updating to 22.04 (Jellyfish) and it didn’t fix my problem.

Comment: Unless it causes any issue which affects your work, just ignore it.

Comment: Think of it as more of an information message not an error and like @Archisman Panigrahi said if it starts not an issue.

Comment: It says EDAC not ETAC ;)

Answer (score 0):

Enable Error Checking in your BIOS or blacklist the `skx_edac` kernel module.

```
smod | grep -i edac
```

edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add

```
blacklist edac_core
```

reboot and the notice is gone